# Use javascript to calculate corresponding field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a beginner with jQuery and need to figure out how to automatically update one field when another has been changed. The code I have works for when the input field is changed, but I don't know how to find (and change) the corresponding field. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdy0enna/)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id='auto-calc'>
            <input></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>(cm)</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id='auto-calc'>
            <input></input>
    </div>
    <div >
        <p>(inches)</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id='auto-calc'>
            <input></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>(kg)</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id='auto-calc'>
            <input></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>(lbs)</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#auto-calc input').change(function () {
        alert($(this));
    });
});
```

So with this, if (cm) changed, I would want to automatically change (inches), and vice versa. Same for (kg) <--> (lbs).

Any ideas? I know that I pretty close, I just can't figure out this last little part

this html will be repeated throughout my entire form. So there will be several cm/in and lbs/kg fields that will need to be corresponded to each other

Comment: Do you mean you will have some arbitrary number of sets of these forms, each with independent values? For example one form might have 2 cm and 8 kg, another 4 cm and 1 kg, etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple fields with the same unit, it's easier to uses classes for the input, like eg `class="cm"`, and group corresponding fields together. An example for `inch` to `cm` in this adjusted [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ump6n2n9/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.cm').change(function () {
    $(".inch").val($(this).val() / 0.393701);
 });
});
```

If you would e.g. group corresponding fields in a container div with the class `fieldgroup`, this can be adjusted to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.cm').change(function () {
    $(this).closest(".fieldgroup").find(".inch").val($(this).val() / 0.393701);
 });
});
```

to change only the value of the corresponding `inch` input.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to go with your second suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The ID attribute of an HTML element must be unique within a document. I suggest "in", "cm", "lbs", "kg". Put the ID on the input element so you can change its value directly.

Once you've done that, you'll need four 'change" functions, which is OK. When "in" changes, you can then set `$(#kg").value` and so on

Comment: I will put this in an edit, but this html will be repeated throughout my entire form. So there will be several cm/in and lbs/kg fields that will need to be corresponded to each other

Comment: They will all have to be unique: "in1", "in2", etc.

Comment: I feel like there is another way. If I could traverse the DOM from $(this) in the javascript. Somehow hop over to the next and previous input and somehow check if those are the valid, corresponding fields. And if they are, change them acordingly

Comment: See the answer by @matthias_h who suggests using classes rather than IDs.  And don't forget to accept his answer if it is the one you adopt.